# Binomial Probability and Raisins in Cake Problem

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> You, your parents, your sister, go to visit grandma for her birthday. Grandma made a cake for the party. If she puts $20$ raisins in the cake at random in the cake, and she divides the cake into $5$ equal pieces, what's the probability that your sister gets no raisins?

Let $X$ be the number of raisins in your piece.
Aside: I think $X$ is the number of raisins for each person in the family.

$X \sim Bin(n=20, \theta=1/5)$

The probability that your sister gets gets no raisins is

> $P[X\in \{3,4,5,6\}]=P[X=3]+P[X=4]+P[X=5]+P[X=6]$

I don't understand the solution.

I think we should calculate $P[X=0]$ instead of 
$P[X\in \{3,4,5,6\}]$.

Also consider:If your sister gets no raisins, then you can at most get $8$ raisins but at least $4$ raisins. $8$ in the case where the $4$ raisins that didn't get in her slice gets into your slice and $4$ assuming someone else received her portion. Then shouldn't we calculate $P[X\in\{4,5,6,7,8,\}]$?

Comment: I agree that you should calculate $P[X=0]$ as well, that is assuming that each respective raisin is equally likely to have occurred in each respective slice of cake independently of one another.

Comment: As for "you can at most get 8 raisins but at least 4"... don't you consider it possible that grandma just so randomly happened to get all 20 raisins in her slice while neither you nor your sister got any raisins in yours, or that you happened to get the 20 raisin slice while noone else gets any at all?

Comment: $P[X=3]+P[X=4]+P[X=5]+P[X=6] \approx 0.7072$ so if that was correct, you would have thought five times that (about $3.5$) would be the expected number of people with no raisins.  It is obviously far too high

Comment: Assuming that "at random" means each raisin is equally likely to be in any of the slices, then each raisin has a probability of $4/5$ of not being in your sister's slice, And there are 20 raisins.

Comment: So everyone assumes that the sister takes just one of the five pieces (which is rarely the case)...

Comment: @PaulSinclair $P[X=0] = (\frac{4}{5})^{20}$ where X is the number of raisins in her piece?

Comment: Yes, since the events of each raisin not being in her slice are independent of each other (having a raisin in a slice does not make it more or less likely other raisins will be), the probability of all these events happening together is their product.